# Firebase error 'NSInvalidArgumentException' on initialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, cocoapods

I have an iOS project which includes Firebase and Google Toolbox For Mac via Pods:

```
target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac', '~> 2.1'
    pod 'GTMSessionFetcher', '~> 1.1'
    pod 'gtm-logger', '~> 0.0.5'

    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

Configured in AppDelegate:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

-(instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];

    [FIRApp configure];

    return self;
}
```

When I run the project, I get this error:

```
<FIRMessaging/INFO> FIRMessaging library version 1.2.2
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSData gtm_dataByGzippingData:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10a548e88'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a326f65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109da0deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a32f48d +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a27cf7a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a27cb28 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   MyApp                         0x0000000107115ec1 -[FIRNetwork postURL:payload:queue:usingBackgroundSession:completionHandler:] + 331
    6   MyApp                         0x000000010710b053 -[FIRClearcutLogger sendNextPendingRequestWithCompletionHandler:] + 570
    7   MyApp                         0x000000010710aaf9 -[FIRClearcutLogger sendLogsWithCompletionHandler:] + 447
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a9edef9 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010aa0e49b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a9f4988 _dispatch_queue_drain + 2215
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a9f3ea9 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 601
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a9f6af2 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1420
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a9f6561 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 111
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010ad3f712 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010ad3f1ed start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Based on other answers, I have set `-ObjC` in my project's and target's `Other Linker Flags`, but I still get this error.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

```
[FIRApp configure];
```

it must be in applicationDidFinishLaunching method. You can't configure it after init and alloc appdelegate because application isn't finished launching yet.

Comment: I've added it to the top of my `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method and I get the error: `The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add [FIRApp configure] to your application initialization` - which seems like exactly what I've done.